# Applying an case when conditional to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replicate a Case Statement within my python script (involving pandas) that is applied to a dataframe and fills a new column based on how each row is processed, but it seems like every row is falling into the else condition due to every value in the new column being `Other`. My first thought is that it is do to the `any()` condition that I have used, but I feel like I could be using the wrong approach completely. Any advice on the direction I should take?

**Example rows:**

```
index | source_name
1 | CLICK TO CALL - New Mexico
2 | Las Vegas Community Partner
3 | Facebook - Test Camp - Los Angeles
4 | Google - Test Camp - Los Angeles

index | landing_page_url
1 | NaN
2 | https://lp.example.com/fb/la/test/
3 | https://lp.example.com/fb/la/test/?utm_source=facebook
4 | https://lp.example.com/google/la/test/?utm_source=google
```

**Code Criteria:**

```
# Criteria
fb_landing_page_crit = [
    'utm_source=facebook', 
    'fbclid',
    'test.com/fb/'
]
fb_source_crit = [
    'fb',
    'facebook'
]
google_landing_page_crit = [
    'gclid'
]
google_source_crit = [
    'click to call',
    'discovery',
    'call',
    'website',
    'landing page',
    'display - lp'
]
local_listings_source_crit = [
    'gmb'
]
partner_source_crit = [
    'vegas community',
    'new orleans community',
    'dc community',
]
```

Conditional:

```
def network_parse(df):
    if isinstance(df, str):
        if any(x in df['landing_page_url'] for x in fb_landing_page_crit):
            return 'Facebook'
        elif any(x in df['landing_page_url'] for x in google_landing_page_crit):
            return 'Google'
        elif any(x in df['source_name'] for x in fb_source_crit):
            return 'Facebook'
        elif any(x in df['source_name'] for x in google_source_crit):
            return 'Google'
        elif any(x in df['source_name'] for x in local_listings_source_crit):
            return 'Local Listings'
        elif any(x in df['source_name'] for x in partner_source_crit):
            return 'Partner - Community Partnership'
        else:
            return 'Other'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

**Function Call:**

```
df['network'] = df.apply(network_parse, axis=1) # Every row returns "Other"
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing a series to network_parse then testing to see if the series is a string.  This will always be false.  In your updated solution you instead test isinstance(df['landing_page_url'], str) which is a string unless its NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better approach to the problem. Rather than using contains methods, I decided to run a regex search to see if the combined list values are found within the column row and if they are present, then apply that value. Found below are my updates:

**Lists:**

```
fb_landing_page_crit = [
    'utm_source=facebook', 
    'fbclid',
    'test.com\/fb\/'
]
fb_landing_page_regex = "|".join(fb_landing_page_crit)

google_landing_page_crit = [
    'gclid'
]
google_landing_page_regex = "|".join(google_landing_page_crit)

fb_source_crit = [
    'fb',
    'facebook'
]
fb_source_regex = "|".join(fb_source_crit)

google_source_crit = [
    'click to call',
    'discovery',
    'call',
    'website',
    'landing page',
    'display \- lp'
]
google_source_regex = "|".join(google_source_crit)

local_listings_source_crit = [
    'gmb'
]
local_listings_source_regex = "|".join(local_listings_source_crit)

partner_source_crit = [
    'vegas community',
    'new orleans community',
    'dc community',
]
partner_source_regex =  "|".join(partner_source_crit)
```

Function:

```
def network_parse(df):
    if isinstance(df['landing_page_url'], str):
        if bool(re.search(fb_landing_page_regex,df['landing_page_url'].lower())) or bool(re.search(fb_source_regex,df['source_name'].lower())):
            return 'Facebook'
        if bool(re.search(google_landing_page_regex,df['landing_page_url'].lower())) or bool(re.search(google_source_regex,df['source_name'].lower())):
            return 'Google'
        if bool(re.search(local_listings_source_regex,df['source_name'].lower())):
            return 'Local Listings'
        if bool(re.search(partner_source_regex,df['source_name'].lower())):
            return 'Partner - Community Partnership'
        else:
            return 'Other'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

Function call:

```
df['network'] = df.apply(network_parse, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now, the problem is not the `any` but the `x in df['source_name']` part (I took `source_name` as it is simpler to explain there). You check if any row of the dataframe is *equal* to (e.g.) `'Google'`, not if it contains the word. To achieve the latter, you could nest the `for` statements:

```
...
if any((x in y for y in df['landing_page_url']) for x in fb_landing_page_crit):
    return 'Facebook'
```

However, I am pretty sure this is not the most elegant and efficient way, as it loops multiple times over the same column, but for smallish dataframes it might be ok. Otherwise it might help you find a more efficient solution.

Edit: To investigate your problem, you could run the following two snippets, where the first one gives `False` and the second one gives `True`:

```
test = ['This', 'thought']

a = ['This is', 'a', 'longer Text than', 'I thought']
print(any(x in in a for x in test))  # This is principally what you coded


test2 = ['This', 'I thought']
print(any(x in a for x in test2)
```